# After Successful Installation Magento2 -AdminURL Not Found on the server

Tags: magento2

Kindly suggest me what could be the reason, that AdminURL is not loading on the server.

magento2 installation was successful. however I am unable to login to AdminURL (The requested URL was not found on this server)

```
Caches clearing:
```

Cache cleared successfully

[Progress: 1383 / 1386]

Disabling Maintenance Mode:

[Progress: 1384 / 1386]

Post installation file permissions check...

For security, remove write permissions from these directories: '/usr/local/var/www/html/magento2/app/etc'

[Progress: 1385 / 1386]

Write installation date...

[Progress: 1386 / 1386]

[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.

[SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin_m8uuu

Nothing to import.

Command that I used for installing the Magento2

```
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento2/" --db-host="127.0.0.1" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="Admin" --db-password="#######" --admin-firstname="Magento" --admin-lastname="User" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="AUD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --search-engine="elasticsearch7" --elasticsearch-host="127.0.0.1" --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

PHP version :
PHP 7.4.25 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2021 15:38:15) ( NTS )

HTTPD Version:
Server version: Apache/2.4.51 (Unix)

Server built:   Oct  7 2021 22:24:56

Elasticsearch Details:

```
{
  "name" : "dhfdgfhdshfdshgjfghdj",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_brew",
  "cluster_uuid" : "lJGfdfdfdff",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2-SNAPSHOT",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "unknown",
    "build_date" : "2021-01-16T01:34:41.142971Z",
    "build_snapshot" : true,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Database MySQL : 8.0

Composer version:Composer version 2.1.9 2021-10-05 09:47:38

I have also added an composer.jason and auth.json at the folder `var/www/html/magento2/var/composer_home`

I have also modified php.ini file

```
[PHP]
;extension=intl
;extension=soap
;extension=xsl
;extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
```

Removeed ; from the above lines of php.ini file.

the below configurations are updated.

```
max_execution_time=18000
max_input_time=1800
memory_limit=4G
```

Kindly suggest me, what could be the reason for not loading Adminurl.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Lavanya, turn on development mode and try to access the admin side. If you are lucky, it will give you some kind of indications. You can also check for any logs or reports which you can find under var directory..

Comment: Does your frontend loading properly without any error?

Comment: Dhiren Vasoya
  frontend also broken.